# Hibernate transaction management without Spring

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions

i want to use Hibernate without Spring, i setup Hiberante in this way:

```
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

But now I get this Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
```

There is any way to let Hibernate automanage transaction like Spring does? Must I open and close transaction manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not according to the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) at least. You have various options to use transactions in a managed as well as a JTA environment, but you'll have to code in the `Transaction` bit

Comment: I would like to have a single session per http request, i should have a filter in Tomcat to open an close session? I hoped there were something to do this automatically... thank you,

Comment: I thought about a Filter to open and close... is this a good choice for you?

Comment: Yes, thats one of the ways recommended in the reference guide. AOP is another way. sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is a new addition in Hibernate 3 making it very convenient to get the session for the current transaction, down at the persistence layer.